# "Cannot resolve to a type"

Tags: java, 2d

Developing a 2D game's engine but I've come across an obstacle.

```
package GameState;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameStateManager {

private ArrayList<GameState> gameStates;
private int currentState;

public static final int MENUSTATE = 0;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final int LEVEL1STATE = 1;

public GameStateManager() {

    gameStates = new ArrayList<GameState>();

    currentState = MENUSTATE;
    gameStates.add(new MenuState(this));
    gameStates.add(new Level1State(this));

}

public void setState(int state) {
    currentState = state;
    gameStates.get(currentState).init();
}

public void update() {
    gameStates.get(currentState).update();
}

public void draw(java.awt.Graphics2D g) {
    gameStates.get(currentState).draw(g);
}

public void keyPressed(int k) {
    gameStates.get(currentState).keyPressed(k);
}

public void keyReleased(int k) {
    gameStates.get(currentState).keyReleased(k);
}

}
```

The game state Level1State cannot resolve to a type. Before this I was getting an instantiate type error. I am using eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse has no bearing on anything.  Where did you define the class Level1State?  You call a constructor that takes a GameManager as an argument.  I don't see it.  Maybe the JDK doesn't either.  Your formatting is terrible.  Learn Java coding standards and start paying attention to format, style, and readability.

Comment: And what class is `Level1State` supposed to be? You didn't include it anywhere in your code so how are we supposed to know what it is?

Comment: Does your class `Level1State` is in same package `GameState`? Or else you've to import that class.

Answer (score 0):

"cannot resolve to a type" means that the compiler has seen the `new` keyword, and it understands that what follows this keyword must be a type, but the compiler does not know of any type called `Level1State`.

So, you have to let the compiler know that there is a type called `Level1State`.

In java, this is usually done with an `import` statement.

If you have questions that are so fundamental, then you need to start reading books.  You cannot learn a programming language one keyword at a time, with one stackoverflow question per keyword.